# Using `System.Drawing.Color` in a F# Fable app

Tags: .net-core, f#, fable-f#

I've been attempting to use `System.Drawing.Color` in my Fable app, converting a a `Color` into a simple `rgba` css string:

```ml
module Color =
    let rgbaString (color: System.Drawing.Color) =
        let alpha = float color.A / 255.0
        String.Format("rgba({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})", color.R, color.G, color.B, alpha)
```

Unfortunately, the Fable compiler throws an error like the one below for r, g, b, and alpha values:

```
ERROR in ./src/App/App.fs
Module Error (from ./node_modules/fable-loader/index.js):
/everybodykurts/MyApp/src/App/App.fs(13,50): (13,57) error FABLE: Cannot resolve System.Drawing.Color.get_R
 @ ./src/App/App.fsproj 1:0-25 1:0-25
```

I've been trying to use F#'s type extensions to add a `get_R` and `R()` method to `System.Drawing.Color` but this doesn't seem to work.

```ml
type System.Drawing.Color with 
    member this.R() = this.R
    member this.G() = this.G
    member this.B() = this.B
    member this.A() = this.A
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 4):

Fable is an F# to javascript compiler. It can compile most of F#, but very little of .Net BCL (Base Class Library).

It simply doesn't know what `System.Drawing.Color` is.

Comment: True, [here](https://fable.io/docs/dotnet/compatibility.html#.NET-Base-Class-Library) is the complete list of what from BCL is supported in Fable.